# design pattern for managing object dependencies

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have to to find solution for the following problem :

I have a lot of model objects. Some model objects depend on other model objects. When the referenced model object changes dependents must be invalidated. I need to store list of my currently invalidated objects, so I can show it to the user and give him a chance to regenerate the objects if he wants to do that. The problem is how would I go with organizing and storing which dependencies an object has, and how to give and receive information when some object changes / become invalidated.

Someone can give idea , or maybe some similar pattern exists for this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> The observer pattern (aka. Dependents, publish/subscribe) is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods.